# full path of Blobstore callback url

Tags: android, google-app-engine, servlets, blobstore, google-cloud-endpoints

Does anyone know the full path of the callback url that the blobstore uses?

Say I specify `upload` in `blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload")` as the callback. Does the blobstore call

`http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/myapp/v1/upload` or does it use `http://localhost:8888/upload`?

I am trying to troubleshoot why my app-engine instance is not getting a callback from the Blobstore.  BTW I am using the official example at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Complete_Sample_App

Answer (score 0):

It will not be full _ah... path, it would be based on second one. If you are following the official example, it has an index.jsp, which you can either debug via firebug or just view source of the generated page, it will have clear url.